# Method that returns true or false at x percentage

Tags: java

i'm looking for a method that answers randomly true or false by a given percentage Integer. for example:

```
percent(100); //Will always 100% return true
percent(50); //Will return 50% true, or 50% false
percent(0); //Will always 100% return false, etc..
```

Here is what I came up with, but for some reason it's not working as it should be:

```
public static boolean percent(int percentage)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    return ((rand.nextInt((100-percentage)+1))+percentage)>=percentage;
}
```

I need a very accurate and real method, please help it's too complicated it's giving me a headache

Comment: Right now you're subtracting 'percentage' and then adding 'percentage' so the expression is reduced to 'rand.nextInt(101)' is that what you want?

Comment: "For some reason it's not working as it should be." *How* is it not working? What's your expectation, what's the result? Have you stepped through and watched it? Just dumping code here and saying "it's not working" is seldom helpful. Answering some of the above questions could indeed help you solve the problem yourself in many cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you are just overthinking it:

```
return (rand.nextInt(100) < percentage);
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

I would break it into smaller pieces to understand:

```
public boolean rollDie(int percentGiven)
{
  Random rand = new Random();
  int roll = rand.nextInt(100);
  if(roll < percentGiven)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Frequently, naming conventions and breaking code across more lines (instead of many method calls stacked in a single line) can make it easier to solve problems.  Here I am using explicit names that make it easy to read.  This is good for beginners like me that do not do well interpreting very compact code.

Comment: `return rand.nextInt(100) < percentGiven` just if you want to join those smaller pieces

Comment: Right, there is an answer to this question with that statement already.

Answer (score 4):

```
public boolean percent(int p){
    Random r=new Random();
    return r.nextInt(100)<p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy enough if you pick up a random number between 1-100. **For example** 55 for the case percent(50) this will be false if you assume that the number between 1-50 are true and the rest are false. Given the fact that you accept that rand() is totally random this shoud solve your problem.

So
`if (random_num >= percent)` **changed**
    `return true;

else

 return false;`

Comment: Not sure that this works: if my percent is 100 I want it to be true 100 percent of the time, but the random number will only be 100 once out of 100 times.

Comment: You don't mind acoording to your question. The given number will be 100 and the random number will be always be equal or less than 100... This will return true

Comment: Wasn't my question, but you have `>=` not `<=`, and a random number from 1-100 will only be `>=` 100 one time in a hundred.